# What is wrong with the following code for insertion in a binary search tree in c++?

Tags: c++, data-structures, tree, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

What is wrong with the following code for insertion in a binary search tree in c++?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

struct node{
int value=0;
node *left=NULL,*right=NULL;
}*root=NULL;

Insert(int value,node *root);
InsertNode(int value,node *root);

int main()
{
Insert(5,root);
Insert(7,root);
Insert(3,root);
return 0;
}

Insert(int value,node *root)
{
if(root==NULL){
    root=new node; root->value=value;cout<<endl<<value<<"inserted"<<endl;
}
else
    {InsetNode(value,root);}
}

InsertNode(int value,node *root)
{
if(value<root->value){
    root->left=new node;
    Insert(value,root->left);
}
else{
    root->right=new node;
    Insert(value,root->right);
}
}
```

This produces following errors when compiled with g++ in ubuntu

```
9:29: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘;’ token
 Insert(int value,node *root);
                             ^
10:33: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘;’ token
 InsertNode(int value,node *root);
                                 ^
 In function ‘int main()’:
14:14: error: ‘Insert’ was not declared in this scope
 Insert(5,root);
              ^

At global scope:
 error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘Insert’ with no type [-fpermissive]
 Insert(int value,node *root)
                            ^
In function ‘int Insert(int, node*)’:
 error: ‘InsetNode’ was not declared in this scope
  {InsetNode(value,root);}
                       ^

At global scope:
29:32: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘InsertNode’ with no type [-fpermissive]
 InsertNode(int value,node *root)
```

Also, I need help in understanding the errors.

Comment: Errors due to missing return type of functions, classical example of bad style of programming.

Comment: _@Abhishar Sinha_ Just get the **basic** syntax right. What's actually unclear about the compiler error messages?

Comment: Isn't int the default return type and since the functions doesn't return any value, the compiler should show warning, not error

Comment: @AbhisharSinha There's no _default return type_ in c++ (I believe there's none that way in c either).

Answer (score 1):

In C++ return type of function is mandatory and cannot be omitted:

```
void Insert(int value,node *root);
void InsertNode(int value,node *root);
```

the same for function definition. That was about errors.

Now for program style:

- Using global and local variable of the same name is a direct way to ask for troubles, you have global `root` and local parameters of the same name.
- If you use c++11 anyway you should use `nullptr` instead of `NULL`
- `using namespace std;` does not make your program better either.
- If you write code in C++ your class `node` should have properly defined ctor, dtor and other method to provide proper memory management.

Did I miss something?

Answer (score -1):

As Slava said the functions declaration (and definition) lack any return type. In your case line 9 should become: 
    `void Insert(int value,node *root);`

In addition `node` is not a type `struct node` is.
You should use the `typedef struct foo{ ... } node;`

Comment: "node is not a type struct node" - that is not correct for C++